# Installing pycairo under ubuntu

Tags: python, cairo, pycairo

For some reason I can't get python to find cairo.

When I did ./waf configure I got

```
Setting top to                           : /home/user/pycairo/py2cairo-1.10.0
Setting out to                           : /home/user/pycairo/py2cairo-1.10.0/build_directory
./configure()
Checking for 'gcc' (c compiler)          : ok
Checking for program python              : /usr/bin/python
Checking for python version              : (2, 7, 2, 'final', 0)
Checking for library python2.7           : yes
Checking for program python2.7-config    : /usr/bin/python2.7-config
Checking for header Python.h             : yes
Checking for program pkg-config          : /usr/bin/pkg-config
Checking for 'cairo' >= 1.10.0           : yes
Configuration:
PREFIX                                   : /usr/local
LIBDIR                                   : /usr/local/lib
```

So next I ran ./waf install.

tried

```
import cairo
ImportError: No module named cairo
```

Now I am pretty stumped on what to do next.
I checked /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages and it is there but that is the only package there. I also noticed "dist-packages" which I think that is where it's meant to go?

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is wrong with the *packaged* version? And didn't cairo switch to GI?

Comment: Wasn't aware of any packaged version. - I couldn't use pip or easy_install to install it.

Comment: Don't use python packaging. Use *Ubuntu* packaging.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is wrong with using the *packaged* version, with full *Ubuntu* support?

> http://packages.ubuntu.com/python-cairo
>
> Python bindings for the Cairo vector graphics library
>
> http://packages.ubuntu.com/python-gi-cairo
>
> Python Cairo bindings for the GObject library

The "latest" way of using Cairo should be via gobject introspection (second package):

```
from gi.repository import cairo
```

which uses mostly auto-generated API from the GI repository that is consistent across various programming languages.

Comment: I get ERROR:root:Could not find any typelib for cairo

Comment: Try `aptitude install python-gi-cairo`. This should pull in the typelib.

Comment: I get Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "python-gi-cairo" after a bit of googling I got to python-cairo. Thanks for all your help

Comment: The links in my post take you directly to the Ubuntu web site, actually. What Ubuntu version do you use? Older than "p"?

Comment: I am running 11.10, but `aptitude install python-cairo` worked flawlessly.

Comment: Yes, but that is AFAICT the old API. 12.04 and onwards should have the new one.

Comment: Has anyone even *tried* python-gi-cairo? There is not enough introspection data for it to be usable. I think it’s more about accepting Pycairo Context objects is GTK. The package even depends on python-cairo.

Anyway I got bored with patching pycairo and made cairocffi: http://packages.python.org/cairocffi/

Answer (score 7):

I like to suggest its cffi-based version which is more common it seems and can be installed on Ubuntu 17.10 at least from apt-get (or apt)

```
sudo apt-get install python-cairocffi python3-cairocffi
```

Answer (score 1):

in Ubuntu 14.04 I did this:

```
cd /home/username/Programming/Repositories/
sudo git clone git://git.cairographics.org/git/pycairo
sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev libjpeg-dev  libgif-dev
cd pycairo
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link, all the instructions are given [here](https://github.com/atizo/pycairo/blob/5ad4300e71fe977ad5ca3d911e05b340b108de6e/INSTALL).

```
git clone https://github.com/atizo/pycairo/
cd pycairo 
run python setup.py install
```

You will be able to import cairo in python after this

Answer (score 0):

go to this [url](https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html#windows) for more information OR:

**Debian / Ubuntu**

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python3-dev python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-wheel python3-cffi libcairo2 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libffi-dev shared-mime-info
```

**macOS**

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

**Windows**

Dear Windows user, please follow these [steps](https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html#windows) carefully.