# Installing py2cairo-1.10.0 in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, installation

I tried installing py2cairo-1.10.0 using the instructions given in the INSTALL file but while configuring using ./waf configure the execution stops showing the following error

```
./options()
Setting top to                           : /home/shubham/Documents/Internetworking/py2cairo-1.10.0 
Setting out to                           : /home/shubham/Documents/Internetworking/py2cairo-1.10.0/build_directory 
./configure()
Checking for 'gcc' (c compiler)          : ok 
Checking for program python              : /usr/bin/python 
Checking for python version              : (2, 7, 4, 'final', 0) 
Checking for library python2.7           : yes 
Checking for program python2.7-config    : /usr/bin/python2.7-config 
**command ['/usr/bin/python', '/usr/bin/python2.7-config', '--includes'] returned 1**
```

Can you please help to solve this problem ?

Comment: Do you need exactly version 1.10.0, or another version would be fine?

Comment: Any version is fine with me

Comment: aptitude install python-gi-cairo 

worked for me
refrence
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754118/installing-pycairo-under-ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is installing it as an Ubuntu package. Open a terminal and issue:

```
sudo apt-get install python-cairo
```

Current version in Raring is 1.8.8

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. But do you know what the problem was while manually configuring the package ?

Comment: the script tries to execute 'python python-config --includes', while the correct command is 'python-config --includes'.

Answer (score 2):

In spite of this being a old thread, I had the same problem trying to compile py2cairo from git in my kubuntu 14.04 using virtualvenv.

```
Checking for program python2.7-config    : /usr/bin/python2.7-config 
command ['/home/mario/progs/python/venvs/science/bin/python', '/usr/bin/python2.7-config', '--includes'] returned 1
```

My solution was to use autogen.sh as suggested in the INSTALL.

```
$ python -c "import sys; print sys.prefix"
/home/mario/progs/python/venvs/science

$ ./autogen.sh --prefix=/home/mario/progs/python/venvs/science
```

And, then

```
 $ ./configure
 $ make
 $ make install
```

I had to resort to `sudo make install` just because other package needed to find the pycairo.h file in /usr/local/. Otherwise, the above commands did the job installing pycairo correctly. All tests passed!

Regards

Answer (score 1):

your original question is quite relevant when one is very much decided NOT installing things GLOBALLY. this is my case, I am trying to install pygtk, pycairo, pygobject in a virtual environment. I didn't manage yet, but I will update this answer when I am done.

when you say "any version" of pycairo, seems that 1.8.10 is the best you can have:
https://gist.github.com/ches/1094799

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this. It is a bug, see bugzilla for pycairo in #80688.

This is happening because the python config script (my version is python2.7-config but your version may differ, under /usr/bin most likely) went from being a python script to a csh script but it is called as a python script. If you check the log file you will see that it gets a syntax error - of course, because it is trying to run a csh script as python.

I just sudo mv'd a python version of this script into /usr/bin and it worked fine. I got the python version from a ubuntu system and the target system was ubuntu. Not the best approach to a workaround but I got pycairo installed.

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix is to simply adjust the broken script instead of pulling it from another distro as suggested. It's a one line change...

if you run: `./waf configure -vv` you can see where/what is broken.

```
File "/opt/src/py2cairo-1.10.0/.waf-1.6.3-3c3129a3ec8fb4a5bbc7ba3161463b22/waflib/Tools/python.py", line 162, in check_python_headers
    for incstr in conf.cmd_and_log(conf.env.PYTHON+[conf.env.PYTHON_CONFIG,'--includes']).strip().split():
```

Adjust file @ line 162:

```
sudo nano /opt/src/py2cairo-1.10.0/.waf-1.6.3-3c3129a3ec8fb4a5bbc7ba3161463b22/waflib/Tools/python.py
```

Change-From:

```
for incstr in conf.cmd_and_log(conf.env.PYTHON+[conf.env.PYTHON_CONFIG,'--includes']).strip().split():
```

Change-To:

```
for incstr in conf.cmd_and_log([conf.env.PYTHON_CONFIG,'--includes']).strip().split():
```

Re-Run:

```
root@box:/opt/src/py2cairo-1.10.0# ./waf configure
  ./options()
Setting top to                           : /opt/src/py2cairo-1.10.0
Setting out to                           : /opt/src/py2cairo-1.10.0/build_directory
  ./configure()
Checking for 'gcc' (c compiler)          : ok
Checking for program python              : /usr/bin/python
Checking for python version              : (2, 7, 14, 'final', 0)
Checking for library python2.7           : yes
Checking for program python2.7-config    : /usr/bin/python2.7-config
Checking for header Python.h             : yes
Checking for program pkg-config          : /usr/bin/pkg-config
Checking for 'cairo' >= 1.10.0           : yes
Configuration:
PREFIX                                   : /usr/local
LIBDIR                                   : /usr/local/lib
'configure' finished successfully (0.391s)
root@box:/opt/src/py2cairo-1.10.0#
```